# How to control the form that opened another form from this last in C#?

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio, formclosing

I'm writing a code where when the user clicks a button, a child form pops up and the user types in information. When the child form comes up, the parent is minimized. I want the parent form to come back up when the user clicks the x button. I'm trying to set the FormWindowState property back to normal in the childform_FormClosed event, but the child form closes while the parent continues to be minimized. I'm using VS community 2019; I saw someone that was able to access the form closing event property through the properties window in the design tab, but I can't find where that is in my version of VS, so I wrote this code in. I've tried the following:

In child form:

```
private void ChildForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    ParentForm frm = (ParentForm)Application.OpenForms["ParentForm"];// find open form
    frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could register the Closed event within the parent. Those are also available 'outside' the form it self.

For example:  (pseudo code)

```
public partial class FormParent : Form
{
    private FormChild _formChild;

    public void ButtonOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // if the formChild already exists, don't create a new one.
        if(_formChild != null)
        {
            _formChild.BringToFront();
            return;
        }

        _formChild = new FormChild();
        _formChild.Closed += FormChildClosed;
        _formChild.Show();
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
    }
 
    public void FormChildClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // don't forget to deregister the event, so the old FormChild can be garbage collected.
        _formChild.Closed -= FormChildClosed;
        _formChild = null;
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    }
}

public partial class FormChild : Form
{
    public FormChild()
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

This is what you asked,

---

This is what I advise, using the ShowModal, which blocks the current method execution. So after the method, you can continue doing what you want to do.

```
public partial class FormParent : Form
{
    private FormChild _formChild;

    public void ButtonOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _formChild = new FormChild();
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        _formChild.ShowModal();
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    }
}

public partial class FormChild : Form
{
    public FormChild()
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm going to give it a try through the parent view first; for the FormChildClosed event in the parent form, is there a way to access that physically through the design tab? Or will VS recognize that it is called if I type it out?

Comment: Sending it through the parent form worked like a charm, just as you have it. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

To have a clean design you should use a form creator pattern and pass the source form like:

> ParentForm.cs

```
WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
ChildForm.Create(this).ShowDialog();
```

> ChildForm.cs

```
static public ChildForm Create(Form sender)
{
  ChildForm form = new ChildForm();
  form.Sender = sender;
  return form;
}

private Form Sender;

private void ChildForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (Sender != null)
      Sender.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
}
```

You can also encapsulate more if you want:

> ParentForm.cs

```
ChildForm.Run(this);
```

> ChildForm.cs

```
static public void Run(Form sender, bool isDialog)
{
  if (sender != null)
    sender.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
  ChildForm form = new ChildForm();
  form.Sender = sender;
  if ( isDialog )
    form.ShowDialog();
  else
    form.Show();
}

private Form Sender;

private void ChildForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (Sender != null)
      Sender.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Is the form creator pattern a different way to initialize the form, in place of the ChildForm form = new ChildForm(), or in addition to it? I haven't tried this method before. Also, what information is the sender passing, a bool? What is activating the form closed event? Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, using the Create static method you don't need to instantiate it, like you can see in the code. You can set the default constructor as private if you want, if the case of having it public is not nedeed.